# Swift4: Error while decoding json from file

Tags: ios, json, swift4

This is my first post, so I hope everything is as structured as it should be.
I hope anybody can help me to solve my issue.

I have the following issue while decoding JSON in Swift from a downloaded file:

The vocabulary.json file contains the following:

```
[
 {
   "english": "one",
   "deutsch": "eins",
   "theme": "numbers"
 },
 {
   "english": "two",
   "deutsch": "zwei",
   "theme": "numbers"
 }
]
```

[JSON in file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nUkd.png)

My swift 4 - code:

```
public struct Vocabulary: Codable{
    let english: String
    let deutsch: String
    let theme: String
}


func decodeData(){
    DataManager.getJSONFromURL("vokabeln") { (data, error) in

        guard let data = data else {
            return
        }
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()

        do {
            let vocabulary = try decoder.decode(Vocabulary.self, from: data)
            print(vocabulary)
        } catch let e {
            print("failed to convert data \(e)")

        }
    }
}

public final class DataManager {
    public static func getJSONFromURL(_ resource:String, completion:@escaping (_ data:Data?, _ error:Error?) -> Void) {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            let url = URL(string: "https://onedrive.live.com/xxxxx/vokabeln.json")
            let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url!, options: .uncached)
            completion(data, nil)
        }
    }
}
```

If I decode the Json from the following multi string:

```
    public let vokabeln: String = """
[
{
    "english": "one",
    "deutsch": "eins",
    "theme": "numbers"
},
{
    "english": "two",
    "deutsch": "zwei",
    "theme": "numbers"
}
]
"""
```

it works, but if I try to decode it from the file I receive the following error message:

> failed to convert data dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "The given data was not valid JSON.", underlyingError: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.})))

Thank you in advance.

Kind regards,

Kai

Comment: Your JSON is an array of dictionaries, so according to your `Vocabulary` class, it should be an array of Vocabulary objects.

Comment: Paste the URL into a browser and check if the JSON is valid. The error message says it's not. And **never** load data from a remote URL with `Data(contentsOf`.

Comment: ok, thank you for the hint. How do I have to load it instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this

`let vocabulary = try decoder.decode(Vocabulary.self, from: data)`

to this

```
let vocabulary = try decoder.decode([Vocabulary].self, from: data)
```

It will give an array of `Vocabulary` just like `[Vocabulary]`.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Happy to help :). and accept the answer if it helped you.

Answer (score -2):

I was getting a very similar error:

> caught: dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [],
>   debugDescription: "The given data was not valid JSON.",
>   underlyingError: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840
>   "Badly formed object around character 64."
>   UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Badly formed object around character
>   64.})))

But for a completely different reason:

My local json was created like this:

```
"""
{
    "name": "Durian",
    "rate": 600,
    "city": "Cali"
    "description": "A fruit with a distinctive scent."
}
"""
```

The error message is quite obvious. I had forgot to place `,` after "Cali".

If I understand this correctly, to count 64 characters you have to start counting from the **beginning** of the line where "name" is. Meaning there are 4 empty characters before in each line. Hence the number ~64. You don't need to count the spaces at the line of `{` :)

Placing the comma resolved the issue.

Comment: Don't *guess* .This `Codable` error tells you exactly what and **where** the error is.

Comment: Patience sensei. Until recently I didn't have to get deep into `Codable` 1. does it tell you that a comma is missing? It just says its badly formed 2. starting from the `"n` until `li"`, I counted 43 characters. Now imagine you have a 2000 long character json and had this issue. You wouldn't know unless some other dev has posted a small easy to understand issue :) 3. What I initially did was just see `dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context` and tried understanding that...until later I found out that I need to look into the entire errror

Comment: 1. No, but you can *infer* it 2. Space characters matter and the crucial character is the character before `"description"` With 2000 characters you can extract the substring with the appropriate `String` API

Comment: _"is the character before "description"_. But no where in the error you can infer that it's before "description" or am I missing something? Nor I understand what you mean by _you can extract the substring with the appropriate String API_ Can you elaborate? I'm not posting this as my greatest answer. Just that I searched this error...found this post. Its answer wasn't applicable so I pasted my own answer. I conveyed my knowledge. And as a 9k user, I'm sure other newbies (or occasionally a  seasoned dev) would benefit from this answer.

Comment: JSON is a pretty manageable format. There are only a few rules you have to memorize. For example like literal Swift dictionaries JSON key/value pairs are comma separated. With this basic knowledge you can see (infer) the missing comma.

Comment: @vadian are you suggesting that the answer is not worthy? Because there are multiple reasons your encoding could not work...1. lack of a json key 2. value being `null` 3. value having wrong type 4. json being incorrect. I was the first 3 where for the first time ever I ran into the 4th kind. I shared my answer with the rest of the community. Only time/upvotes will tell if this answer was useful or not. I kinda feel like senior devs eventually forget what its like to be a newbie dev. Just like how grandparents grow impatient of their grandchildren sometimes :)

Comment: I'm not judging the worth of the answer. I'm suggesting to  learn to *read* (and understand) `Codable` errors rather than *guessing*

Comment: Agreed. I should have read the error in its entirety. I just read `dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context` and was perplexed...